# Переклад «Частих запитань про сайти Stack Exchange»

Tags: discussion, help-translated

<sub>Це сторінка міститиме переклад [суспільного «FAQ for Stack Exchange sites»](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931).</sub>

<sub>Структура така:

    • у «запитанні» — зміст (перелік питань);

    • у «відповідях» — розділи (окремі відповіді).</sub>

<sub>Коментувати, робити виправлення і перекладати неперекладені секції — запрошуємо. Але: це має бути суто переклад оригіналу, без особистого внеску (якщо є думки щодо зміни самого змісту, а не розвитку перекладу — це до оригіналу, а не сюди).</sub>

---

## Суспільний FAQ (запитання, що часто ставлять)

**Для сайтів мережі Stack Exchange 2.0**

Для офіційних настанов від Stack Exchange відвідайте [Довідковий центр](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/).

### Відповідаючи на запитання

- [Як мені написати хорошу відповідь на запитання?](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/211)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>[[оригінал]](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659)</sub>

**Як написати хорошу відповідь**

- Пишіть зрозуміло.
- Наводьте приклади.
- Посилайтеся на додаткову інформацію і подальше читання.
- Цитуйте релевантний матеріал, щоби не примушувачи користувача натискати на кожне надане посилання задля розуміння суті відповіді.
- Переглядайте Вашу відповідь, щоби включати більше інформації, коли вона надходить.
- Обов'язково стежте за коментарями до Вашої відповіді, щоби мати змогу відгукнутися з поясненнями, як нові запитання з'являться стосовно Вашої відповіді.